# Better way to disable console inside unit tests

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I wonder if there is a better way to disable console errors inside a *specific* Jest test (i.e. restore the original console before/after each test).

Here is my current approach:

```
describe("Some description", () => {
  let consoleSpy;

  beforeEach(() => {
    if (typeof consoleSpy === "function") {
      consoleSpy.mockRestore();
    }
  });

  test("Some test that should not output errors to jest console", () => {
    expect.assertions(2);

    consoleSpy = jest.spyOn(console, "error").mockImplementation();
 
    // some function that uses console error
    expect(someFunction).toBe("X");
    expect(consoleSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });

  test("Test that has console available", () => {
    // shows up during jest watch test, just as intended
    console.error("test");
  });
});
```

Is there a cleaner way of accomplishing the same thing? I would like to avoid `spyOn`, but `mockRestore` only seems to work with it.

Comment: I accidentally ended up hiding a real error doing this. Ideally, first thing you should try to do is diagnose a warning or error. If it's _truly_ benign, there are plenty of answers below to help in hiding it.

Comment: @DevinRhode, it's decent advice But there are cases where console output is expected as part of a test, e.g. testing the error-handling code in a function. And sometimes you may want to call 3rd-party code that console logs, rather than mocking it out.

Answer (score 357):

For particular spec file, Andreas's is good enough. Below setup will suppress `console.log` statements for all test suites,

```
jest --silent
```

(or)

To customize `warn, info and debug` you can use below setup

****tests**/setup.js** *or* **jest-preload.js** configured in `setupFilesAfterEnv`

```js
global.console = {
  ...console,
  // uncomment to ignore a specific log level
  log: jest.fn(),
  debug: jest.fn(),
  info: jest.fn(),
  // warn: jest.fn(),
  // error: jest.fn(),
};
```

**jest.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
    verbose: true,
    setupFilesAfterEnv: ["<rootDir>/__tests__/setup.js"],
};
```

Comment: Hi! `setupTestFrameworkScriptFile` is deprecated in favor of `setupFilesAfterEnv`.

Comment: Mocking `global.console` is indeed a simple way to go, and can be done through any configured `setupFilesAfterEnv `. Beware to mock all native methods of the `console` object or you may encounter other unexpected errors.

Comment: Note that if you then want to check on the mock (or clear it) you will need to refer to it as console.log, e.g., expect(console.log).toBeCalledTimes(1).

Comment: You can also add the `"silent": true` option to the `jest.config.js` file

Answer (score 193):

If you want to do it just for a specific test:

```
beforeEach(() => {
  jest.spyOn(console, 'warn').mockImplementation(() => {});
});
```

To make TS happy, you can use:

```
beforeEach(() => {
  jest.spyOn(console, 'error').mockImplementation(jest.fn());
});
```

Comment: It doesn't work in my tests, I still have some `console.warn` during test. Tested multiple times, it's not bulletproof

Comment: This is a good solution. It allows me to continue looking at other console.warn (or console.log) for debugging.

Comment: It doesn't work. It may have worked in the past, but now it's broken.

Comment: It works, though perhaps not as you want depending on where you put the statements (see https://jestjs.io/docs/setup-teardown#order-of-execution-of-describe-and-test-blocks). Once this runs, it will stay that way for the rest of the test run since console is a global object. (Node v16.0.0. Jest 24.9.0).

Comment: For me this creates a mock that I can check has been called the appropriate number of times but doesn't suppress the resulting message.  To do that I had to overload the global object in my setup.

Comment: I don't know why this answer has so many upvotes. It's a great way to disable console functionality before each test (as the name `beforeEach` would imply), but it doesn't answer the OP's question, which is "how to disable console errors inside a _specific_ Jest test".

Comment: @fenix.shadow it's very easily adaptable to doing it inside a single test. Anything that can be done within a `beforeEach` can be done within an `it`. As for people saying it doesn't work... it does for me. You may want to also catch the error thrown by Vue Test Utils's default error handler.

Comment: The missing part of adapting it to be used in a single test is calling `consoleSpy.mockRestore()` afterward. The code given in this solution will leave console logging disabled for all tests in the JS file that are executed afterward which can hide errors. The OP's original code sample fixes this.

Comment: Spies are isolated per test

Comment: If you are working on a TS project, use `jest.fn()` instead of `() => {}`

Answer (score 86):

As every test file runs in its own thread there is no need to restore it if you want to disable it for all test in one file. For the same reason you can also just write

```
console.log = jest.fn()
expect(console.log).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

Comment: Thank you for the info on that matter. It does make sense :)
I was looking for a way to make it that way only inside a specific test without having to restore it (I initially thought that was the behaviour by default), but I guess beforeEach does the trick.

Comment: But the next tests in the same file will still have it mocked, right? Depending on the situation, that may not be ideal.

Answer (score 30):

I found that the answer above re: suppressing `console.log` across all test suites threw errors when any other `console` methods (e.g. `warn`, `error`) were called since it was replacing the entire global `console` object.

This somewhat similar approach worked for me with Jest 22+:

#### package.json

```
"jest": {
  "setupFiles": [...],
  "setupTestFrameworkScriptFile": "<rootDir>/jest/setup.js",
  ...
}
```

#### jest/setup.js

```
jest.spyOn(global.console, 'log').mockImplementation(() => jest.fn());
```

Using this method, only `console.log` is mocked and other `console` methods are unaffected.

Answer (score 13):

To me a more clear/clean way (reader needs little knowledge of the jest API to understand what is happening), is to just manually do what mockRestore does:

```
// at start of test you want to suppress
const consoleLog = console.log;
console.log = jest.fn();

// at end of test
console.log = consoleLog;
```

Comment: You also need to cover console.info, console.error, console.warn, etc.

Comment: @michael-liquori why do you need to restart the console.log? I think after every describe the mocks are cleared

Comment: @Jhonatan I don't think it does clear after every describe, though I haven't tested this recently to be sure. According to [jest docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html#resetmocks-boolean) there is a `clearMocks` and `resetMocks` configuration option but they both default to `false`, **and** neither of those actually restore the initial implementation even if set to `true`.

And, considering this is a config option that could be changed at some point, I think it is best practice to clean up manually to ensure your tests won't cause problems in the future.

Comment: Note that if the test fails, the rest of the test will not run so `console.log = consoleLog` will not be called. Better to `beforeEach(() => jest.restoreAllMocks())`.

Answer (score 9):

```js
beforeAll(() => {
    jest.spyOn(console, 'log').mockImplementation(() => {});
    jest.spyOn(console, 'error').mockImplementation(() => {});
    jest.spyOn(console, 'warn').mockImplementation(() => {});
    jest.spyOn(console, 'info').mockImplementation(() => {});
    jest.spyOn(console, 'debug').mockImplementation(() => {});
});
```

Answer (score 5):

If you are using command `npm test` to run test then change the `test` `script` in **package.json** like below

```
{
  ....
  "name": "....",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest --silent",         // add --silent to jest in script like this
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  ...
}
```

Or else you can directly run command `npx jest --silent` to get rid of all logs and errors when testing

Answer (score 5):

Here's all the lines you may want to use. You can put them right in the test:

```js
jest.spyOn(console, 'warn').mockImplementation(() => {});
console.warn("You won't see me!")
expect(console.warn).toHaveBeenCalled();
console.warn.mockRestore();
```

Comment: As of Sept 23, this answer is incomplete. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/56512217/5250103

Answer (score 4):

Weirdly the answers above (except [Raja](https://stackoverflow.com/users/777147/raja-jaganathan)'s great answer but I wanted to share the weird way the others fail and how to clear the mock so no one else wastes the time I did) seem to successfully create the mock but *don't* suppress the logging to the console.

Both

```
const consoleSpy = jest.spyOn(console, 'warn').mockImplementation(() => {});
```

and

```
global console = {
   warn: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {});
}
```

successfully install the mock (I can use expect(console.warn).toBeCalledTimes(1) and it passes) but it still outputs the warning even though the mock implementation seemingly should be replacing the default (this is in a jsdom environment).

Eventually I found a hack to fix the problem and put the following in the file loaded with SetupFiles in your config (note that I found sometimes global.$ didn't work for me when putting jquery into global context so I just set all my globals this way in my setup).

```
const consoleWarn = jest.spyOn(console, 'warn').mockImplementation(() => {});
const consoleLog = jest.spyOn(console, 'log').mockImplementation(() => {});
const consoleDebug = jest.spyOn(console, 'debug').mockImplementation(() => {});
const consoleError = jest.spyOn(console, 'error').mockImplementation(() => {});


Object.defineProperty(global, 'console', {value: {
                                            warn: consoleWarn,
                                            log: consoleLog,
                                            debug: consoleDebug,
                                            error: consoleError}});
```

It feels ugly and I then have to put code like the following in each test file since beforeEach isn't defined in the files referenced by SetupFiles (maybe you could put both in SetupFilesAfterEnv but I haven't tried).

```
beforeEach(() => {
  console.warn.mockClear();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Since `jest.spyOn` doesn't work for this (it may have in the past), I resorted to `jest.fn` with a manual mock restoration as pointed out in [Jest docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-function-api#mockfnmockrestore). This way, you should not miss any logs which are not empirically ignored in a specific test.

```js
const consoleError = console.error

beforeEach(() => {
  console.error = consoleError
})

test('with error', () => {
  console.error = jest.fn()
  console.error('error') // can't see me
})

test('with error and log', () => {
  console.error('error') // now you can
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Kudos to @Raja's top answer. Here is what I am using (I would comment, but can't share a multi-line code block in a comment).

With jest v26, I'm getting this error:

```
We detected setupFilesAfterEnv in your package.json.

Remove it from Jest configuration, and put the initialization code in src/setupTests.js:
This file will be loaded automatically.
```

Therefore, I had to remove the `setupFilesAfterEnv` from my jest config, and add this to `src/setupTests.js`

```js
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44467657/jest-better-way-to-disable-console-inside-unit-tests
const nativeConsoleError = global.console.error

global.console.error = (...args) => {
  if (args.join('').includes('Could not parse CSS stylesheet')) {
    return
  }
  return nativeConsoleError(...args)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ways to suppress console (logs, warning, error)

Option-1: Updating configuration in `jest.config.js`

```json
module.exports = {
  
  silent: true,

  <OTHER_PROPERTIES>
};
```

Option-2:

```json
scripts": {
    "test": "jest --silent",         
  },
```

Option-3: In case need to suppress for particular spec

```
// Your test spec 
beforeAll(() => {
  // Silence console logs and warnings
  jest.spyOn(console, 'log').mockImplementation(() => {});
  jest.spyOn(console, 'warn').mockImplementation(() => {});
  jest.spyOn(console, 'error').mockImplementation(() => {});
});

afterAll(() => {
  console = { ...originalConsoleMethods };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to use `process.env.NODE_ENV`. *This way one can selectively choose what to show (or not) while running tests:*

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
  console.log('Show output only while in "development" mode');
} else if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'test') {
  console.log('Show output only while in "test" mode');
}
```

or

```
const logDev = msg => {
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
    console.log(msg);
  }
}
logDev('Show output only while in "development" mode');
```

This will require this configuration to be placed on `package.json`:

```
"jest": {
  "globals": {
    "NODE_ENV": "test"
  }
}
```

*Note that this approach is not a direct solution to the original question, but gives the expected result as long as one has the possibility to wrap the `console.log` with the mentioned condition.*

Comment: What the author of the question is how to disable console.log on testing. This solution is not optimal.

Comment: For copy-pasters out there: replace `===` with `!==` according to your needs. I've been using this approach for years and it works flawlessly, but I do make adjustments according to my needs.

Comment: Doesn't answer the actual question.

Comment: This is a hacky solution and not customizable. What if disable only for a specific test and not the other one?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple function that will ignore specific logs that match the supplied regex:

```
export default function ignoreLogs(
  logType: 'log' | 'info' | 'warn' | 'error',
  match: RegExp
) {
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
  const logFn = console[logType];
  jest.spyOn(console, logType).mockImplementation((...args) => {
    if (typeof args[0] === 'string' && args[0].match(match)) {
      return;
    }

    logFn(...args);
  });
}
```

Usage:

```
ignoreLogs('warn', /some warning that is logged by an internal library/)
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`jest-fail-on-console`](https://github.com/ValentinH/jest-fail-on-console) library has an useful feature for this.
Just add the following in your Jest config file:

```js
failOnConsole({
  silenceMessage: (errorMessage) => {
    if (/Part of error message I need to ignore/.test(errorMessage)) {
      return true
    }
    return false
  },
})
```