# Errors when using Enzyme with React Native (import glyphmap)

Tags: react-native, jestjs, enzyme

I'm trying to set up Enzyme testing for my React Native project. I've been getting various errors in various scenarios.

### Scenario 1

When I try to set up a test for one of my components, I get this error:

```
    /Users/TuzMacbookPro2017/Development/QMG-local/APPS/ELECTRO/node_modules/@expo/vector-icons/Zocial.js:1
    ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){import glyphMap from './vendor/react-native-vector-icons/glyphmaps/Zocial.json';
                                                                                                    ^^^^^^^^
    SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

Some relevant files

#### test file

```js
import React from "react";
import renderer from "react-test-renderer";
import { mount, ReactWrapper } from "enzyme";
import LoginView from "../src/screens/LoginView";

describe("LoginView", () => {
  const wrapper = mount(<LoginView />);

  it("can get through the damn test file", () => {
    expect(true).toBe(true);
  });
});
```

#### jest.config.js

```js
module.exports = {
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ["<rootDir>setup-tests.js"],
  transformIgnorePatterns: [
    "node_modules/(?!(jest-)?react-native|@react-native-community|react-native-elements)"
  ],
  preset: "react-native"
};
```

#### babel.config.js

```js
module.exports = function(api) {
  api.cache(true);

  return {
    presets: ["babel-preset-expo"]
  };
};
```

#### package.json

```js
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "eject": "expo eject",
    "test": "node ./node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js --watchAll --bail",
    "testff": "node ./node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js --watchAll --bail"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo",
    "testEnvironment": "node",
    "globals": {
      "__DEV__": true
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/samples": "2.1.1",
    "@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.3.4",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "expo": "^32.0.0",
    "flow-bin": "^0.98.1",
    "native-base": "^2.12.1",
    "pluralize": "^7.0.0",
    "react": "16.5.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-native": "0.57",
    "react-native-elements": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-geocoding": "^0.3.0",
    "react-native-global-font": "^1.0.2",
    "react-native-indicators": "^0.13.0",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scrollview": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-material-dropdown": "^0.11.1",
    "react-native-render-html": "^4.1.2",
    "react-native-uuid": "^1.4.9",
    "react-navigation": "^3.9.1",
    "react-redux": "^6.0.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "redux-saga": "^1.0.2",
    "redux-test-utils": "^0.3.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "sugar": "^2.0.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.4.5",
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.4.4",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.4.5",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "axios-mock-adapter": "^1.16.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.1",
    "babel-jest": "^24.8.0",
    "babel-preset-expo": "^5.0.0",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "^4.0.1",
    "enzyme": "^3.9.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.12.1",
    "fetch-mock": "^7.3.3",
    "jest": "^24.8.0",
    "jest-enzyme": "^7.0.2",
    "jest-expo": "^32.0.0",
    "jsdom": "^14.1.0",
    "mock-async-storage": "^2.1.0",
    "prettier-eslint": "^8.8.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "^16.8.6",
    "redux-mock-store": "^1.5.3",
    "redux-saga-tester": "^1.0.460"
  },
  "private": true,
  "rnpm": {
    "assets": [
      "./assets/fonts"
    ]
  }
}
```

#### setup.tests.js

```js
import Adapter from "enzyme-adapter-react-16";
import { configure } from "enzyme";
import jsdom from "jsdom";

import "react-native";
import "jest-enzyme";

function setUpDomEnvironment() {
  const { JSDOM } = jsdom;
  const dom = new JSDOM("<!doctype html><html><body></body></html>", {
    url: "http://localhost/"
  });
  const { window } = dom;

  global.window = window;
  global.document = window.document;
  global.navigator = {
    userAgent: "node.js"
  };
  copyProps(window, global);
}

function copyProps(src, target) {
  const props = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(src)
    .filter(prop => typeof target[prop] === "undefined")
    .map(prop => Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(src, prop));
  Object.defineProperties(target, props);
}

setUpDomEnvironment();

configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });
```

#### imports from the component under test

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  Image,
  Input,
  Button,
  ThemeProvider,
  Overlay
} from "react-native-elements";
import { View, Text, Picker } from "react-native";
import { DotIndicator } from "react-native-indicators";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { login, assignUser } from "../redux/actions/authActions";
import F8StyleSheet from "../components/F8StyleSheet";
import { Dropdown } from "react-native-material-dropdown";
import { KeyboardAwareScrollView } from "react-native-keyboard-aware-scrollview";
import User from "../models/User";
import uuid from "react-native-uuid";
```

### Scenario 2

So that's a problem, but then something else interesting happens. When I swap out my `LoginView` for a super simple component, the test runs, but brings up some new errors that cast some suspicion on my rendering setup.

#### SimpleView.js

```js
import React from "react";
import { Text, View } from "react-native";

export default (SimpleView = ({ params }) => (
  <View>
    <Text>SimpleView</Text>
  </View>
));
```

#### test

```js
import React from "react";
import renderer from "react-test-renderer";
import { mount, ReactWrapper } from "enzyme";
import SimpleView from "./__mocks__/SimpleView";

describe("LoginView", () => {
  const wrapper = mount(<SimpleView />);

  it("can get through the damn test file", () => {
    expect(true).toBe(true);
  });
});
```

#### errors

```js
 PASS  tests/LoginView.test.js (6.058s)
  LoginView
    ✓ can get through the damn test file (4ms)

  console.error node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:506
    Warning: <Text /> is using incorrect casing. Use PascalCase for React components, or lowercase for HTML elements.
        in Text (created by Component)
        in Component (created by SimpleView)
        in View (created by Component)
        in Component (created by SimpleView)
        in SimpleView (created by WrapperComponent)
        in WrapperComponent

  console.error node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:506
    Warning: The tag <Text> is unrecognized in this browser. If you meant to render a React component, start its name with an uppercase letter.
        in Text (created by Component)
        in Component (created by SimpleView)
        in View (created by Component)
        in Component (created by SimpleView)
        in SimpleView (created by WrapperComponent)
        in WrapperComponent

  console.error node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:506
    Warning: <View /> is using incorrect casing. Use PascalCase for React components, or lowercase for HTML elements.
        in View (created by Component)
        in Component (created by SimpleView)
        in SimpleView (created by WrapperComponent)
        in WrapperComponent

  console.error node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:506
    Warning: The tag <View> is unrecognized in this browser. If you meant to render a React component, start its name with an uppercase letter.
        in View (created by Component)
        in Component (created by SimpleView)
        in SimpleView (created by WrapperComponent)
        in WrapperComponent
```

Answer (score 0):

One reason for your issue could be the `"preset": "react-native"` line in your `jest.config.js`.  Try changing it to `"preset": "jest-expo"`.  This is the way the expo documentation (https://docs.expo.io/versions/v35.0.0/guides/testing-with-jest/) explains how to setup jest with your project.

Comment: You can rephrase this into a decent answer, if you do NOT explain how you are breaking the rules of this community (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead) and to not seem like a clarification question. Phrase it like "one reason for your problem could be ..., in that case this ... should solve it). That would make an acceptable below-50 answer. As it is, you are asking for flags as NAA ("not an answer") and for trouble because of working around rules....

Comment: Gotcha.  Thank you, I'll make the necessary changes

Comment: I'm not using expo on the project. Will this still work?

Comment: @JonathanTuzman Any solution you found? Even i am not using expo

Comment: add import 'jsdom-global/register'; to specific page. Not in package.json. The answer is misleading

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue, and can't find a solution. So I had to mute error output:

```
jest --silent
```

ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49591765/4975761