# How to restore a mock created with jest.mock()?

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs

Apparently mock.mockRestore() does not restore the original implementation of a mock created using jest.mock()

```
// a.js
export default class A {}


// b.js
import A from './a';
export default class B extends A {}


// test.js
import A from './a';
import B from './b';

jest.mock('./a');
jest.mock('./b');

const b = new B();

test('instanceOf', () => {
    A.mockRestore();
    B.mockRestore();
    expect(b).toBeInstanceOf(A); // fails
});
```

Comment: Indeed, mock.mockRestore() restores the default implementation of the module, this is helpful if you wanna mock it on some tests and use original in other tests

Answer (score 56):

[`mockFn.mockRestore`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-function-api#mockfnmockrestore) only works for a mock function created with `jest.spyOn`:

```js
const obj = {
  func: () => 'original'
}

test('func', () => {
  const mock = jest.spyOn(obj, 'func');
  mock.mockReturnValue('mocked');

  expect(obj.func()).toBe('mocked');  // Success!

  mock.mockRestore();
  expect(obj.func()).toBe('original');  // Success!
})
```

`jest.spyOn` wraps the original function and provides `mockRestore` as a way to restore the original function.

---

`jest.mock` calls work a little differently.

`Jest` takes over the `require` system and `jest.mock` tells `Jest` that it should return the module mock instead of the actual module whenever it is required.

This means that the module mock doesn't wrap the original module, it completely replaces the original module in the `require` system.  So `mockRestore` may be defined on mock functions within the module mock, but calling it doesn't restore the original implementation.

---

`jest.mock` is typically used when you want to mock an entire module for the whole test.

It is particularly useful when using ES6-style `import` statements since `babel-jest` hoists `jest.mock` calls and they run before anything else in the test file (including any `import` statements):

```js
import A from './a';  // <= A is already mocked...

jest.mock('./a');  // <= ...because this runs first

test('A', () => {
  // ...
}
```

---

There isn't an easy way to restore the original module during a test that uses `jest.mock` since its primary use is to mock a module for an entire test.

If you are trying to use both a mock and the original implementation during the same test there are a few options:

- Mock one particular function using `jest.spyOn` and restore it using `mockRestore`
- Use [`jest.doMock`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestdomockmodulename-factory-options) to avoid the hoisting behavior of `jest.mock`...just note you also need to use `require` within the scope that uses `jest.doMock` instead of using a top-level `import`
- Use [`jest.requireActual`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestrequireactualmodulename) at any time to `require` the original module

Comment: > Modules that are mocked with jest.mock are mocked only for the file that calls jest.mock.

Comment: How does using `jest.doMock` help here?  The mock still seems to survive between tests in a suite.

Comment: @robross0606 [jest.doMock](https://jestjs.io/docs/26.x/jest-object#jestdomockmodulename-factory-options) is not hoisted to the top, so when you multiple test suites in one file you can mock a module in one suite and not mock in the other.

Comment: `autoMockOff` should do the trick but is not working for me. I have to call [`dontMock`](https://jestjs.io/docs/26.x/jest-object#jestdontmockmodulename) to restore a mock created by `doMock`.

Comment: None of these worked for me so I just created a separate file as jest.mock is only for a single file.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you cant use spyOn,
you can do something like this:

```
// test.js

jest.mock('./a');
import A from './a';

A.mockImplementation(params => 'mockVal');
const actualA = jest.requireActual('./a');

test('instanceOf', () => {
    A.mockRestore(); // acts like mockReset()
    A.mockImplementation((params) => {
        return actualA(params);
    });
});
```