# How to mock SQL Server connection pool using Jest?

Tags: javascript, typescript, jestjs, mocking, ts-jest

I am trying to write a jest unit test for a function that utilizes `mssql`.

```
import * as sql from "mssql";

let pool: sql.ConnectionPool = null;

export async function handler() {
  if (pool === null) {
    try {
      pool = new sql.ConnectionPool("");
      await pool
        .request()
        .input("SomeInput", sql.NVarChar(255), "input")
        .execute("SomeStoredProcedure");
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  }
}
```

What would be the simplest way to mock the sql methods and assert they have been called?

```
import { handler } from "../src/main";

describe("test handler", () => {
  it("should succeed", async () => {
    const requestFn = jest.fn();
    const executeFn = jest.fn();
    const inputFn = jest.fn();
    
    // Mock mssql connection pool with above functions
    // *????????*
    
    await handler();
    
    // Expect the functions have been called
    expect(requestFn).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(executeFn).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(inputFn).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

[Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/mssql-testing-vehuj/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can mock the `mssql` package by using an [jest ES6 Class Mocks](https://jestjs.io/docs/es6-class-mocks#calling-jestmock-with-the-module-factory-parameter). You can achive that by using:

```js
const mockExecute = jest.fn();
const mockInput = jest.fn(() => ({ execute: mockExecute }));
const mockRequest = jest.fn(() => ({ input: mockInput }));

jest.mock('mssql', () => ({
  ConnectionPool: jest.fn(() => ({
    request: mockRequest
  })),
  NVarChar: jest.fn()
}));
```

Have a look at the [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/node-mnbvp5?file=index.test.js) project and run `jest` in the terminal. You should see that the tests are passing.

Comment: @Harry No problem good luck for your tests implementation ;)

Comment: Do I have to restore the mssql module after the test to get the original implementation back?

If so, how to that? I read that it is a bit of a hassle if you mock a complete module with jest.

Comment: @TheDude `jest.mock` is actually used to mock a module for an entire test suite so what would be the use case to get the original implementation back? I recommend you to read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56512217/8583669) that explain well some pattern to mock stuffs in jest.

Answer (score 0):

You need to mock the return value of each function in the chain. You can do this using `jest.fn().mockImplementation(implementation)`

Expanding you example to use this give us the following

```
import { handler } from "../src/main";

let pool;

describe("test handler", () => {
  it("should succeed", async () => {
    const requestFn = jest.fn();
    const executeFn = jest.fn();
    const inputFn = jest.fn();
    
    pool = {
      request: requestFn,
      execute: executeFn,
      inputFn: inputFn,
    };

    requestFn.mockImplementation(() => pool);
    executeFn.mockImplementation(() => pool);
    inputFn.mockImplementation(() => pool);

    await handler();
    
    // Expect the functions have been called
    expect(requestFn).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(executeFn).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(inputFn).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I don't think this solves the problem. The ConnectionPool is created in the handler `pool = new sql.ConnectionPool("");` ...this pool object you've created in the test seems obsolete

Comment: Then I think you need to mock `sql.ConnectionPool("")` to return the mock version of `pool`