# How to mock SQL Server connection pool in node

Tags: node.js, jestjs, node-mssql

I am attempting to mock SQL Server connection pool so that I can test the function of a DAL.

I have a connection pool file

connectionPool.js

```
const sql = require('mssql');
const log = require('../services/logger');

const config = {
  user: process.env.DB_USER,
  password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
  server: process.env.SERVER,
  database: process.env.DATABASE
};

const poolPromise = new sql.ConnectionPool(config)
  .connect()
  .then(pool => {
    log.info('Connected to SQL Server');
    return pool;
  })
  .catch(err => {
    log.error(err, 'Database connection failed');
  });

module.exports = poolPromise;
```

and I use it in the DAL. Very stripped down, but the essentials are there.

```
const {poolPromise} = require('./connectionPool');

const getData = async () => {
  const pool = await poolPromise;
  const request = pool.request()
  const result = await request('SELECT * FROM table');
}
```

This way, the connection pool is only created once per application. (See [How can I use a single mssql connection pool across several routes in an Express 4 web application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30356148/how-can-i-use-a-single-mssql-connection-pool-across-several-routes-in-an-express))

I want to mock the `mssql` module so that the connection pool function still works. I have tried multiple options. [How to mock SQL Server connection pool using Jest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67684327/how-to-mock-sql-server-connection-pool-using-jest) gets me close, but its not quite there.

`__mocks/mssql.js`

```
const mockExecute = jest.fn();
const mockInput = jest.fn(() => ({ execute: mockExecute }));
const mockRequest = jest.fn(() => ({ input: mockInput }));

jest.mock('mssql', () => ({
  ConnectionPool: jest.fn(() => ({request: mockRequest})),
  NVarChar: jest.fn()
}));

const sql = require('mssql');

module.exports = sql;
```

However I get the error

> TypeError: (intermediate value).connect is not a function
>
> 17 |
> 18 | const poolPromise = new sql.ConnectionPool(config)
> 19 |   .connect()
> |      ^
> 20 |   .then(pool => {
> 21 |     log.info('Connected to SQL Server');
> 22 |     return pool;

Answer (score 0):

This *may* be a solution.
A bit of refactoring of connectionPool.js

```
const sql = require('mssql');
const log = require('../services/logger');

const config = {
  user: process.env.DB_USER,
  password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
  server: process.env.SERVER,
  database: process.env.DATABASE
};
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
  config.options = {
    encrypt: false,
    trustServerCertificate: true
  };
}

const connectionPool = new sql.ConnectionPool(config);
const poolPromise = connectionPool
  .connect()
  .then(pool => {
    log.info('Connected to MSSQL');
    return pool;
  })
  .catch(err => {
    log.error(err, 'Database connection failed');
  });

module.exports = poolPromise;
```

Then in `/__mocks__/mssql.js`

```
'use strict';

const mockExecute = jest.fn();
const mockInput = jest.fn().mockReturnValue({ execute: mockExecute });
const mockQuery = jest.fn().mockReturnValue({recordset: 'Mock data'});
const mockRequest = jest.fn().mockReturnValue({
  input: mockInput,
  query: mockQuery
});

const mockTransaction = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
  return {
    begin: callback => callback(),
    commit: jest.fn(),
    rollback: jest.fn()
  };
});

const mockConnect = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
  return Promise.resolve({ transaction: mockTransaction });
});

jest.mock('mssql', () => ({
  ConnectionPool: jest.fn().mockReturnValue({
    request: mockRequest,
    connect: mockConnect
  }),
  Request: mockRequest,
  NVarChar: jest.fn()
}));

const mssql = require('mssql');

module.exports = mssql;
```

It appears to work, but I am not sure if it is correct

Comment: This doesnt work for me; i get an error that the mocks are not initialised; I think because the ES6 class mock (jest.mock) hoists to the top of the code and therefore those variables have not yet been defined.

Comment: Now if i move the mocks to the top manually, then it compiles/runs but I get a "pool.connect is not a function" error.

Comment: I'm also having trouble getting this to work and I get a different error.

The error for me is the following:

`TypeError: Descriptor for property ConnectionPool is non-configurable and non-writable`

Have you been able to get it to work in the meantime?

Oh sorry, I forgot this example was meant to be used with jest.

Anyone being successful to migrating this solution to sinon?