# Asserting whether a method has been called in the created lifecycle hook

Tags: javascript, vue.js, jestjs, vue-test-utils

I'm writing a test using Jest for a Vue application. Now I'm trying to assert whether a certain method is being called when the component is created. For some reason I'm getting back that the method is not a function, but I don't really get why.

Below is my component script:

```
  created() {
    this.fetch();
  },
  methods: {
    async fetch() {
      this.loading = true;

      try {
        await this.fetchDossier();
        await this.fetchDetails();
        await this.fetchBlob();
      } catch (error) {
        this.error = error.response;
      } finally {
        this.loading = false;
      }
    }
  }
```

And this is how my test looks like right now:

```
test('The fetch method should be called when the component has been created.', async () => {
  const fetchMethod = jest.spyOn(Component.methods, 'fetch');

  const wrapper = shallowMount(CaseDetails, {
    global: {
      mocks: {
        $route,
        $store: {
          state: {
            apiConfig: new Configuration({
              basePath: 'https://localhost:3000',
            }),
          },
        },
      },
    },
  });

  await wrapper.vm.$options.created();

  expect(fetchMethod).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

When I assert whether the methods in the fetch method are being called when I call wrapper.vm.fetch() returns a positive. How should I test something like this?

Comment: `await wrapper.vm.$options.created()` - this is a mistake, created is called with wrong context, this is already done by shallowMount . If you want to test how fetch works, you need to stub it before shallowMount, then restore original implementation and call it separately

Comment: I'm quite new to writing tests. How should I write a stub?

Comment: Like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56496998/how-to-restore-a-mock-created-with-jest-mock