# Stop execution JSDOM scripts

Tags: jestjs, jsdom

In test I run request using JSDOM with option '*runScripts*'. Test passed but I get in console

```
'Cannot log after tests are done. Did you forget to wait for something async in your test?'
```

This is because scripts continues to run after test is done. What should I do, to don't get log this error to console? It is code that I run:

```
test('should run request without errors', done => {
  const options: BaseOptions = {
    resources: 'usable',
    runScripts: 'dangerously',
  };
  JSDOM.fromURL('http://localhost:3000/', options).then(dom => {
    setTimeout(function() {
      done();
    }, 60000);
  });
});
```

Comment: I have same problem, this answer seems like a way to go https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44467657/jest-better-way-to-disable-console-inside-unit-tests

Comment: @LudovitMydla, not exactly. I've edit question to give more explaining.

Comment: How about keeping reference to the timeout and clearing it in `afterEach()`? So that Jest wouldn't have a reason to complain

Comment: Or 2 other ideas: 1) Remove `setTimeout()` if it is not necessary for the test case, 2) Smartly use `async`, `await` to get rid of error

Comment: Another idea.... what about `catch` branch of promise? Shouldn't that be handled with `done()` as well?